# Can't figure out how to multiply aliens in my pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

So I've just been writing a dodger game for practice using pygame and python. I've read a lot of tutorials and looked at other similar games to help me. Basically, aliens come down from the top of the screen (they're supposed to be random sizes and speeds and their location is supposed to be random  as well) and the player uses their mouse to move the spaceship to dodge the falling aliens.

I have an if statement that is supposed to multiply the aliens coming down from the top but when I run the game only one alien falls and when it reaches the end of the screen it just disappears. No other aliens appear. The program is still running so the game hasn't ended.

Here is my full code.

```
import pygame
import random
import sys
from pygame.locals import *
alienimg = pygame.image.load('C:\\Python27\\alien.png')
playerimg = pygame.image.load('C:\\Python27\\spaceship.png')

def playerCollision(playerRect, aliens): # a function for when the player hits an alien
    for a in aliens:
        if playerRect.colliderect(a['rect']):
            return True
    return False

def screenText(text, font, screen, x, y): #text display function
    textobj = font.render(text, 1, (255, 255, 255))
    textrect = textobj.get_rect()
    textrect.topleft = (x,y)
    screen.blit(textobj, textrect)

def main(): #this is the main function that starts the game

    pygame.init()

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
    pygame.display.set_caption('Dodge the Aliens') 
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 45)


    pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    aliens = []
    score = 0
    alienAdd = 0
    addedaliens = 0
    gameOver = False
    moveLeft = moveRight = moveUp = moveDown = False
    topScore = 0
    while gameOver==False: #while loop that actually runs the game
        score += 1

        playerImage =   pygame.image.load('C:\\Python27\\spaceship.png').convert() # the player images
        playerRect = playerImage.get_rect()
        screen.blit(playerImage, [300, 250])
        alienImage = pygame.image.load('C:\\Python27\\alien.png').convert() #alien images
        alienRect = alienImage.get_rect()
        screen.blit(alienImage, [ 50, 50 ])
        pygame.display.flip()


        for event in pygame.event.get(): #key controls
            if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE: #escape ends the game
                gameOver = True
            elif event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
                playerRect.move_ip(event.pos[0] - playerRect.centerx, event.pos[1] - playerRect.centery)
        screen.fill((0,0,0))
        pygame.display.flip()


        if not gameOver:
            alienAdd += 1
        if alienAdd == 6: # randomly adding aliens of different sizes and speeds
            aliendAdd = 0
            alienSize = random.randint(8, 25)
            newAlien = {'rect': pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, 500 - alienSize), 0 -alienSize, alienSize, alienSize),
                    'speed': random.randint(1, 8),
                    'surface':pygame.transform.scale(alienImage, (alienSize, alienSize)),
                    }
            aliens.append(newAlien)

        if moveLeft and playerRect.left > 0:
            playerRect.move_ip(-1 * 5, 0)
        if moveRight and playerRect.right < 500:
            playerRect.move_ip(5, 0)
        if moveUp and playerRect.top > 0:
            playerRect.move_ip(0, -1 * 5)
        if moveDown and playerRect.bottom < 500:
            playerRect.move_ip(0, 5)

        for a in aliens:
            if not gameOver:
                a['rect'].move_ip(0, a['speed'])


        for a in aliens[:]:
            if a['rect'].top > 500:
                aliens.remove(a) #removes the aliens when they get to the bottom of the screen

        screenText('Score %s' % (score), font, screen, 10, 0)
        screen.blit(playerImage, playerRect)

        pygame.display.update()

        for a in aliens:
            screen.blit(a['surface'], a['rect'])
        pygame.display.flip()


        if playerCollision(playerRect, aliens):
            if score > topScore:
                topScore = score
            gameOver = True


        clock.tick(30)

    screenText('Game Over!', font, screen, (750 / 6), ( 750 / 6))
    screenText('Press ENTER To Play Again.', font, screen, ( 750 / 6) - 80, (750 / 6) + 50)
    pygame.display.update()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Also, sidenote, whenever I put my code in here I go down every line and indent it. Is there an easier way to do that?

Comment: There's also a `{}` button in the Stack Overflow editor to add code formatting. If you've highlighted multiple lines, it will indent them for you. For a single (or partial) line it will use backticks `\`\``.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in `aliendAdd = 0`, it should be `alienAdd = 0`. This is causing you to keep incrementing `alienAdd` more and more and not hit your if statement of `alienAdd == 6` again.

Comment: I've been staring at this on and off for nearly six hours now and I can't believe I missed that. Thank you.

Comment: @bruceleezard Get an IDE that tells you things like this. E.g., PyCharm or Atom would have immediately let you know that you had an undefined reference, or at least a variable you didn't use anywhere else. If you don't want to switch IDEs, programs like `pylint` can do this to an extent (although that particular one is verbose and overly picky IMO).

Comment: I've used PyCharm before but I just don't like learning new interfaces. I'll look into it though because it would have simplified my life a lot more. Thank you @Two-BitAlchemist

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist could either of you help me with another problem? I have the player character to follow the mouse but for some reason it follows the mouse then glitches back to the top corner. How can I make it just follow the mouse instead of going back to the starting coordinates?

Comment: @bruceleezard I've never used pygame. I suppose if you took the cursor off the side of the screen it could do that if your code didn't accommodate it correctly. Print out the values of the mouse coords and look for oddities or negative numbers where you don't expect and if all else fails, ask a new question here.

Comment: @bruceleezard Please ask a separate question for this other issue. Also, I'm glad that my answer helped you with this issue. Please accept the answer if your original problem has been resolved so it can be removed from the unanswered queue.